# update nested array element of basis of selecting array element in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updating

Below is MongoDB document.

```
`{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("588f09c8d466d7054114b456"), 
 "phonebook" : [
    {
        "pb_name_first" : "Aasu bhai", 
        "pb_phone_number" : [
            {
                "ph_id" : 2, 
                "ph_no" : "+91111111", 
                "ph_type" : "Mobile"
            }
        ], 
        "pb_email_id" : [
            {
                "email_id" : "temp@gmail.com", 
                "email_type" : "Home", 
                "em_id" :1
            },
            {
                "email_id" : "test@gmail.com", 
                "email_type" : "work", 
                "em_id" :2
            }
        ], 
         "pb_name_prefix" : "MR."
    }
 ]
}`
```

I want mongodb query that will update `email_id` data in `pb_email_id` array on basis of `em_id`. If i select `em_id=1` then that record `temp@gmail.com` will update.if i select `em_id=2` then `test@gmail.com` will update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply if-else logic in update call, you can run two separate update calls

```
db.collection.update({'pb_email_id.em_id':1},{$set : {'pb_email_id.$.email_id' : 'temp@gmail.com'}},{multi:true});

db.collection.update({'pb_email_id.em_id':2},{$set : {'pb_email_id.$.email_id' : 'test@gmail.com'}},{multi:true});
```

However you can run a script on collection to apply multiple logic

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
 if(doc.pb_email_id && doc.pb_email_id.length>0){
   for(var i in doc.pb_email_id){
    if(doc.pb_email_id[i].em_id === 1){
      doc.pb_email_id[i].email_id = "temp@gmail.com"}
    else if(doc.pb_email_id[i].em_id === 2){doc.pb_email_id[i].email_id = "test@gmail.com"}
     db.collection.save(db)
     }
  }
 })
```

If you have to apply multiple logic, you can run script, otherwise two update calls if that's as much as needed.

P.S - since you didn't mentioned collection name, I used `db.collection.update` it should be collection name like `db.phonebook.find` etc.